# Issue with $scope using promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I'm trying to set up a simple controller that makes an asynchronous http call using a service. I set up something very similar for another controller I wrote, but for some reason this one isn't functioning. The **console.log($scope.art);** line in the then() block outputs the correct data, but once it's out of the then() block, $scope.art is undefined. Why would this be? I'm very confused!

```
app.controller('FeedbackController', ['$scope','getArt', function($scope, getArt) {
        var art = getArt();
        art.then(function(result) {
            $scope.art = result;
            console.log($scope.art);
        }, function(reason) {
            $scope.error = reason;
        });
        console.log($scope.art);
}])
.factory('getArt', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {
   return function() {

        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.post("/php/getArt.php")
            .success(function (response) {
                if (response == "nope") {
                    deferred.reject("Whoopsie! Something seems to have gone wrong.");
                } else {
                    deferred.resolve(response);
                }
            })
            .error(function () {
                deferred.reject("There seems to be an issue with your connection.");
             });
        return deferred.promise;
   };
 }]);
```

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

The http calls are asynchronous, therefore you `console.log($scope.art);` executes *before* the http call finished.
You can do any post-processing in the `then` callback.

Or if you only need to display the `art` object for the user, it will just appear as soon as the dat is returned by the server. Maybe you can add something like this to indicate that data is beeing loaded from the server:

```html
<div ng-if="!art">loading...</div>
<div ng-if="art">... display it for the user ...</div>
```

Comment: oh jeez louise I am a fool! that makes a lot of sense. thank you!

Comment: Wellcome to javascript & async @CarterScottDavis :)

Answer (score 0):

In the following code

```
app.controller('FeedbackController', ['$scope','getArt', function($scope, getArt) {
    var art = getArt();
    art.then(function(result) { 
        $scope.art = result; //line 4, executed some time in the future 
        console.log($scope.art); //line 5
    }, function(reason) {
        $scope.error = reason;
    });
    console.log($scope.art); //line 9, synchronously, executed right away
}])
```

line 9 gets executed immediately right after the call to the server gets fired, which is before line 4 and line 5 (when the promise is fulfilled), so when that happens $scope.art is still *undefined* (or still has some old value)

For reference, here's an article that explains JavaScript async really well http://tutorials.pluralsight.com/front-end-javascript/introduction-to-asynchronous-javascript